# How to prevent a SVG marker to inherit the stroke-dasharray of its shape?

Tags: svg

I am trying to have solid line at the start/end point of my SVG line but the markers keep the value of the shape using them. Is there any way to prevent that?

Here is my current SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <marker id="start" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="none" stroke="black" />
        </marker>
        <marker id="end" refX="10" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <path id="arrow" d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 L 0 0" fill="none" stroke="black" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <path d="M10 50 L70 50" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="0.75pt" stroke-dasharray="10,4" marker-start="url(#start)" marker-end="url(#end)" />       
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want the circle and the arrow to be solid. I tried adding stroke-dasharray="none" on the circle and the path, with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm, that looks like a webkit bug. `stroke-dasharray="none"` should be the right attribute according to spec, but `stroke-dasharray="0"` works for me in all browsers and it should achieve the same result (according to spec).

Answer (score 1):

Safari 6 seems to ignore the `stroke-dasharray="0"` attribute. The only workaround I was able to find was to set stroke-dasharray to a value bigger than `markerWidth`/`markerHeight`.

Answer (score -1):

Neither `stroke-dasharray="0"` nor `..="none"` doesn't work for me.
[esad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13663557/7664275) inspire me.
But I think better practice is `stroke-dasharray="100%"`